# dynamic casting of base to derived objects

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, dynamic-cast

I am trying to assign derived objects to a vector of base objects, and then cast them back to derived objects. I am not able to do the cast though.

```
struct Base
{
    string foo;
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    string bar;
};
```

I have a function that modifies a vector of base elements. Depending on some conditions, it may create a derived object instead of the base object and push that onto the vector:

```
void foo(vector<Base> &bases)
{
    Base *base;
    if (...)
    {
        base = new Derived;
        base->foo = string("hello");
    }
    bases.push_back(*base) 
}
```

Then I pass in a vector to that function and try to get the contents.

```
vector<Base> bases;
foo(bases);

for (auto it = bases.begin(); it != bases.end(); ++it)
{
    Base *base = &(*it);
    Derived *derived = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(base); 
    // derived == nullptr
}
```

What am I missing here? If I try to access `foo` as a Base object, it works, but when I try to dynamically cast to a Derived object, it fails, despite having been created as a Derived object in the `foo(vector<Base> &bases)` function.

Comment: You can't use `vector<Base>`, you'll end up slicing the `Derived` objects you put into it. Use `vector<unique_ptr<Base>>` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work:

```
void foo(vector<Base> &bases)
{
    Base *base;
    if (...)
    {
        base = new Derived;
        base->foo = string("hello");
    }
    bases.push_back(*base) 
}
```

`vector<>` contains objects, not references. When you `push_back` an object that is understood to be of the base type, only the data that is applicable to the base type is stored (ie, "sliced.").

Instead, store a `Base*` or `shared_ptr<Base>` in the `vector<>`.

It's also worth noting that, in the snippet above, you'll wind up getting access violations whenever the `if()` block is skipped since `base` is never initialized.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot use polymorphism with objects directly, you have to use POINTERS of base objects and then you can cast to derived classes or directly call virtual methods.

Change your system from:

```
vector<Base> bases;
```

to

```
vector<Base*> bases;
```

And update all your code in base of this, and everything will work perfectly  :)

Comment: "everything will work perfectly" - apart from the need to store the objects somewhere, and manage their lifetimes.

Comment: "...update all your code in base of this..." would summarize that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your vector contains `Base` objects, of type `Base`. You might have initialised these by copying derived types; but all that did was copy the `Base` part (which some people call *slicing*), losing any knowledge of the original types.

Polymorphism only works with references or pointers; you'll need a `Base*` in order to manage objects of derived types. How to manage the lifetime of the objects themselves, either stored somewhere else, or with the vector's (preferably smart) pointers owning them, is left as an exercise.